# How to make a IsNull() method

Tags: c#, isnull

I'm trying to make a method similar to .ToString() that checks whether the object is null or not. I just done know how to make it accessible without calling the class

```
public class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(object obj)
    {
        bool val = false;
        if (obj == null)
        { val = true; }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `== null`?  Also, you can simplify your method body to `return obj == null;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the `this` modifier to make it a true extension method as well as making the object static.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this object obj)
    {
        return obj == null;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
var fooIsNull = foo.IsNull();
// which is syntactic sugar for
fooIsNull = ObjectExtensions.IsNull(foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class needs to be static  and you need the "this" keyword before the extended variable type:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this object obj)
    {
        bool val = false;
        if (obj == null)
        { val = true; }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Also, as you are doing a single boolean check, you can return it's results directly:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this object obj)
    {
        return obj == null;
    }
}
```

Here a link to MSDN entry for [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You were correct in thinking that you need a static method.  That's the only way to avoid a null pointer exception for a null value.  You can fake it though with an extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this object obj)
    {
        return obj == null;
    }
}
```

Also note that your implementation, while it works, is overly complex.  You don't need any more than the one line to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this object obj)
    {
        return obj == null;
    }
}
```